# AutoHotKey, Repeat key press

Tags: autohotkey

All I want is a simple keypress of lowercase "v" 4 times with a 1 second delay between. I have tried so many iterations of this simple-sounding action to no avail and the most infuriating thing is that I can get it to work with a capital "V" – but that also emulates a <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> key press. I just don't understand.

```
v::   
Loop, 4  
    {                   
        sleep 10  
        SendInput {V} ; capital V works perfectly fine but includes Shift+v, I don't want a shift  
        sleep 1000        
    }  
return
```

Whereas ...

```
v::  
Loop, 4  
    {                   
        sleep 10  
        SendInput {v} ; Lowercase v, Does absolutely nothing...   
        sleep 1000      
    }  
return
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$v::  
Loop, 4  
    {                   
        sleep 10  
        SendInput v 
        sleep 1000      
    }  
return
```

The [$ prefix](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) works by forcing the keyboard hook to be used and prevents the Send command from triggering the hotkey itself.

Alternative [#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) can be specified somewhere above, so the keyboard hook is implemented for every hotkey after it

Comment: wow the $ worked perfectly, I was never sure what the # or $ prefix' did i had tried the # but not the $ so thank you so very much this solved my, now I feel silly, issue

Comment: Will also try to remember the #useHook and experiment with this again ty so much

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class your_app_ahk_class
$v::
    SetKeyDelay, 1000
    Send {v 4}    
Return
```

I don't know what's the purpose of this, but since the shortcut does not include any control keys, it might be better to limit this to a specific app. The first line in my snippet tries to achieve this.